# How come Mongoose return empty document when find by id of an array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The schema is like that:

```
var feedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {type: Number},
  following: []
});
```

and my code using promise is very simple:

```
  var Feed = require("/models/feed");

  return Feed.find({"following" : id}).exec();
```

I have data like this:

```
{
 id:1, following: [2,3,4]
}
```

but when I set the id for query, it doesn't return anything.  Any idea?

Comment: Where is `id` being set?

Answer (score 1):

It should be working, I am providing an example which works ok, probably you can contrast your logic with this one and know which part could be the problem.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/murvinlai');

var FeedSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  following: [Number]
});

var Feed = mongoose.model('Feed', FeedSchema);

var newFeed = {
  id: 1,
  following: [2, 3, 4]
};

createFeed(newFeed, function(err, feed) {
  if (err) throw err;

  findFeedByFollowingArray(2).then(function(feeds) {
    console.log(feeds); 
    //  [ { _id: 55a486a11ef682b41e13e82a,
    //      id: 1,
    //      __v: 0,
    //     following: [ 2, 3, 4 ] } ]      
  });
});

function createFeed(feed, cb) {
  Feed.create(feed, function(err, feed) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    if (!feed) { return cb(new Error('Feed was not created')); }

    cb(null, feed);
  });
}

function findFeedByFollowingArray(id) {
  return Feed
    .find({following: id})
    .exec();
}
```

Comment: Your example works.  I know it is simple.. but I still dont' know what it doesn't work on mine.. going to try different things again.  Thanks.   at least I know I'm on the right track.

Comment: Find out the problem.  it is because... I store it as number in the array, but when I query (because it is taken the input from url), it is a string. e.g. {following:"2"}, that's why it fails.   Thanks.

Comment: @murvinlai great you could resolve the issue so you'd better to put your `following` property on the your `Schema` accepting only numbers something like this:
`following: [Number]`